# Finding max in generic list directly

Tags: c++-cli

I have a generic C++ CLI list which is populated with integers. I want to find the max value. Normally the list is sorted in ascending order. So I could just take the last item. Or I could sort the list and then take the last item but is there a way to avoid that and just do something like ->Max()?

```
         System::Collections::Generic::List<System::Int32>^ Testlist = gcnew System::Collections::Generic::List<System::Int32>();
         Testlist->Add(1);
         Testlist->Add(2);
         Testlist->Add(3);
         Testlist->Add(4);
         int max = Testlist[Testlist->Count-1];//too iffy..without having to sort, can I get max?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the Linq method to find the [`Max`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb292667.aspx?cs-lang=cpp) of an `IEnumerable`.

```
using namespace System::Linq;

List<Int32>^ list = ...;
Int32 max = Enumerable::Max(list);
```

C++/CLI doesn't support the fancy Linq query syntax, nor extension methods, but all extension methods are just static methods, and you can call that directly. (In C#, we could use the extension method to write `list.Max()`.)

Comment: that was the missing link.

Comment: 2 comments: This method requires a list to have  at list one item. Also: Does this have a performance issue?  I may be imagining this but the app starts a few 10ths of a second slower.

Comment: The System.Linq namespace is in the System.Core assembly. I doubt that this is the first thing that causes that assembly to be loaded.